# How to resolve a list of futures in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, future

I have a call that returns a Future.
However, I need to make n calls so I will get back n futures. I am wondering how I would get the futures to all resolve before proceeding (without blocking the server)

For example,

```
while(counter < numCalls){
    val future = call(counter)
    future.map{  x =>
        //do stuff
    }
    counter += 1 
}

//Now I want to execute code here after ALL the futures are resolved without 
//blocking the server
```

Comment: you can use for ... yield in conjunction with futures

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `Future.sequence(futureList)` to convert a `List[Future[X]]` to a `Future[List[X]]`. And since the latter is just a simple `Future`, you can wait for it to finish with the help of the `Await.ready` or similar helpers.

So you would have to keep a list of the futures you generate. Something like:

```
val futures = new ListBuffer[Future[X]]
while(counter < numCalls) {
    val future = call(counter)
    futures += future
    future.map { x =>
        //do stuff
    }
    counter += 1 
}
val f = Future.sequence(futures.toList)
Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf)
```

which you could also write as:

```
val futures = (1 to numCalls).map(counter => {
    f = call(counter)
    f.map(x => ...)
    f
})
Await.ready(Future.sequence(futures), Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Except if you call Await.ready then you'll block - which is fine for the purposes of illustration, but you shouldn't block in your production code - not if you really can avoid it... and you almost always can avoid it.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush and pasted the wrong line. I meant : val f = Future.sequence(futures.toList). I ended up using a f.map in order to wait for it to resolve

Answer (score 6):

A little more functional:

```
val futures = for {
  c <- 0 until 10
   } yield {
    val f = call(c) 
    f onSuccess {
      case x =>
      // Do your future stuff with x
    }
    f
  }
Future.sequence(futures)
```

Comment: How is this more functional that the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6):

I take it that you want to do something after the Futures are finished ,eg. a callback, without blocking the original call? Then you should do something like this:

```
val futures = for (...) yield {
  future {
  ...
  }
}

val f = Future sequence futures.toList

f onComplete {
  case Success(results) => for (result <- results) doSomething(result)
  case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

So you don't block with an await call, but you still wait for all Futures to complete and then do something on all results. The key aspects is using Future.sequence to join a lot of futures together and then to use a callback to act on the result.