# How to solve connect timeout exception issue in play framework 2.2.1

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I am calling a `web service` in `play framework` with `scala`. The code is following `Producer/Consumer` pattern. Each call to WS takes about 2 seconds. But many such calls are made, that exceed 120 seconds (which is default timeout in play). Hence it throws an exception: `java.net.connectException` after exactly 120 secs.

Questions:

1. Why are time of all calls being added up, rather than treating them individually and hence timeout would not be an issue.
2. I tried one solution of increasing timeout by solving this issue: [fixed ws.timeout](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1971/files) . But for me the issue still exists.
3. Is it a problem of thread or concurrency ?

Here is code of class:

```
class WS(sentenceList: List[String], queue: BlockingQueue[Future[Response]], filename: String) {

  val listofJson = new ListBuffer[(String, JsValue)]
  listofJson.clear

  def callWSProducer() = {

    sentenceList.foreach { name =>
      val data = Json.obj(
        "input_sent" -> name,
        "Filename" -> filename)

      val holder: Future[Response] = WS.url("http://0.0.0.0:8015/endpoint/").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").post(data)
      implicit val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
      queue.put(holder)
    }
  }

  def WSConsumer(): List[(String, JsValue)] = {

    sentenceList.foreach { name =>

      val result = Await.result(queue.take(), 100.second)

      val out = (result.json \ "sentence");

      listofJson += ((name, out));
    }

    return listofJson.toList

  }

}
```

Error i am getting in console:

[error.txt](http://txt.do/1peb)

EDIT:

Let me make the question a little clearer. Firstly, the functions above are called from the the controller (main thread) by creating an object of the above class. The Json list above is returned to the controller, which in turn returns it to the view. Because we have to return the list, the only possible way to do it that we could come up with is using the await (blocking) mechanism.

I know there are threading issues with the code, but could someone at least point those out. All the methods we have tried, either lead to the 120 second timeout mentioned above or the 100 second future timeout when there is some kind of deadlock in our await block, like when we use a solution similar to one mentioned here: [Scala Play Resolve a list of futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012364/scala-play-resolve-a-list-of-futures)

Comment: There are many threading problems with this code, but it depends on how it will be called. There is not enough information in your question to give answer your question. `Execution exception[[ConnectException: connection timed out: /0.0.0.0:8015 to http://0.0.0.0:8015/endpoint/]]`.

Comment: Did you take a look at Play! Iteratee library ? If you are trying to solve the producer-consumer problem in an asynchronous way, Iteratees and Enumerators are the way to go, me thinks.

Comment: @drstevens did u see `error.txt`

Comment: @RahulKulhari Yes, I took the error in my comment from the `error.txt`. It just indicates that the web service at "http://0.0.0.0:8015/endpoint/" is not responding within appropriate amount of time.

Comment: For starters, mixing Futures/Await with a BlockingQueue is a recipe for disaster. Asynchronous programming does not mix well with blocking threads. I think the issue you are having is much too large and general for a stack overflow question. It's hard to help without knowing more about the problem you are solving and seeing the controller code. As @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama mentioned, take a look at other tools like Iteratees/Enumerators and Actors for shared state. You are probably going to want to think about the problem in a completely different way. I doubt there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about why we have to block? I think we can come up with a non-blocking solution for this. But first lets address the timeout issue. For WS you can configure the time timeout using ws.timeout property. I am not sure why that is not working. For experiment set to 0 in your application.conf file

```
ws.timeout=0
```

This is essentially sets timeout to forever. This might open up new problems in your code. I don't know for sure. Now lets look into the blocking/await stuff. How about something like this

```
  object Application extends Controller {

     //using Scala global implicits is a bad practice
     //implicit val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

     //use the play one or even better use a custom execution context read
     //http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools
     implicit val context = play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

     def index = Action.async {
          invokeServices(send your sentence list).map { listOfPairs =>
             //do your transformation here to create the result
          }
     }
     //invokeServices hopefully capture all that you are doing inside the WS class but no blocking 
     //and mutation.  
     def invokeServices(sentenceList: List[String]): Future[List[(String, JsValue)]] = {
       val responses: List[Future[(String, JsValue)]] = sentenceList.map { name =>
          val data = Json.obj(
            "input_sent" -> name,
            "Filename" -> name)

            val response: Future[Response] = 
                WS.url("http://0.0.0.0:8015/endpoint/").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").post(data)
            response.map(result => (name, result.json \ "sentence"))
        }
       //converts List[Future[A]] to Future[List[A]]
       Future.sequence(responses)
     }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this solution but as usual I am getting `play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out: /0.0.0.0:8015 to http://0.0.0.0:8015/endpoint/` after 120 seconds.
The `ws.timeout=0` in `application.conf` doesn't seem to make any difference in Play! 2.2.1 or 2.2.2 RC4.

Comment: I should have aid more attention to the Play 2.2.1 version. It has some issues with ws.timeout https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1739. I am surprised that you didn't see errors when you configured ws.timeout. But if you use Play 2.2.2 then it should work I just tested with this fake endpoint                 ```def endpoint = Action.async {

     val json = Json.toJson(Map("sentence" -> "42"))
     import scala.concurrent.duration._
     play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(Ok(json), 5 seconds)
  }```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done completely async & non-blocking.  Here is an example controller:

```
def pause = Action.async {
  // between 5 and 10 seconds
  val delay = Random.nextInt(5) + 5
  Promise.timeout(Ok(delay.toString), delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}

// future of the total paused time (which isn't total time)
private def allPauses: Future[Int] = {
  Future.sequence {
    for (i <- 1 to 10) yield {
      // max timeout of 15 seconds so everything should be good
      WS.url("http://localhost:9000/pause").withRequestTimeout(15000).get().map(_.body.toInt)
    }
  } map (_.sum)
}

def test = Action.async {
  allPauses.map { seconds =>
    Ok(s"Total paused time was $seconds seconds")
  }
}
```

Use `Future.sequence` to turn a `Seq[Future[A]]` into a `Future[Seq[A]]` and then map that to do something with the resulting values.  Make your controller return a `Future[Result]` so that it is also non-blocking.

Full code example: https://github.com/jamesward/play-futures-with-timeouts